# continuous functional on a finite dimensional compact subset of $C(K)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am reading Chen and Chen's paper "Universal Approximation to Nonlinear Operators by Neural Networks with Arbitrary Activation Functions and Its Application to Dynamical Systems" and cannot understand one argument in proving Theorem 4.

In short, suppose $V_k\subset C(K)$ is compact and $ \dim (V_k) = k $.
Chen has proved that: for any $v\in V_k$, $v$ can be written as $v = \sum_{j = 1}^k v(x_j)T_j(x)$, where $T_j(x)$ is some partition of unity function defined on $x_j\in K$.

Now let $f$ be a continuous functional on $V_k$ and denote $\hat{v} = [v(x_1), ..., v(x_k)x]^{\intercal}$.
I guess at some point in the proof (Equation 37 in Chen's paper), they use a ``fact''  that: there exists a continuous function $g$ such that,
$$
f(v) = g(\hat{v}).
$$
That is, the continuous functional on a finite-dimensional function equals a continuous function.
Can anyone tell me which theorem this is or how we can prove this? Thank you so much!